# Use Sublime text to wrap domain names in quotes

Tags: sublime-text-2

I have a large-ish csv text file of which one column contains a domain name, e.g. `example.com`.

However, to be able to import my file correctly I need to have all occurrences of domain names to be wrapped in quotes, e.g. `example.com` has to become `"example.com"` and `example.co.uk` needs to become `"example.co.uk"`.

How can I wrap all occurrences of domain names in double quotes (without installing any 3rd party addons)?

**UPDATE**

I have tried this regex `[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}` which correctly seems to select all my domain names however, to then wrap them in double quotes seems to prove difficult. Using `"$1"` seems to insert the quotes but also remove the domain name. Even when I just try `$1` my domains are replaced with nothing.

**UPDATE 2**

I'm using version 2.0.2 of Sublime on Ubuntu. I tried the solution listed at **update** above in a blank document but the same problem happens. It's like both `$1` and `\1` are not recognized.

Comment: Have you pressed the ".*" button in the _search_ _and_ _replace_ dialog? Does simpler search work?

Comment: Without the * button ticked, regular expression search doesn't work, right? I can search and replace the domains with anything except for the original value (i.e. the `$1`). So if I replace with `abc` then all my entries become `abc`.

Comment: Very strange indeed. I can only confirm that your way worked for me, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way - `[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}` and `"$1"` - works for me, but try this:
`([A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4})` where replace string is `"\1"`.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the `"\1"` but the same thing happens. All domains are replaced with `""`. Very strange...

Comment: @Luke have you noticed the parentheses around the regex? The shift from `$1` to `\1` is not the only change there.

Comment: You are correct. I didn't notice and indeed, it works!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of figuring out how capturing groups work in regular expressions, you can use Sublime's multiple cursors:

1. Type in the regular expression in the Find drawer as before.
2. Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to select all domain names.
3. Hit <kbd>"</kbd> to wrap them in quotes, just like you would on one domain name.